# PHP function returning error

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to make a function like this:

```
function simplicate () { 

$organization = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization',json_encode($org_payload));

}    

// fetch the newly created organization id
$organization_id = $organization['data']['id'];

//after order is processed run simplicate function
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'simplicate');
```

So i can use it like this:

```
//after order is processed run simplicate function
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'simplicate');
```

But i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function makeApiCall() on a non-object
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/dexport.nl/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/functions.php
>   on line 370

Comment: `$SimplicateApi` isn't available in the function scope. Where are you setting it?

Comment: above the function could that be the reason? @JonStirling

Comment: `$SimplicateApi`  you need to pass it somehow

Comment: @Kevin.a, the reason is in [the scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/174946

Comment: Solved it thanks, who would like to post the answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the function scope. 
Apparently one of the variables was not inside the function i created.